# Store website data in android device(SQLite,Realm or else)?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-webview, android-preferences

I am creating an android application, which i have load URL in to **webView**.

**What exactly i want**

***I want to store website data*** which entered by users and store it in to Database.

Comment: It totally depends on requirements. Personally I use Realm db because it's a lot more simpler. But now with new architecture components sqlite becomes simpler too.

Comment: actually i am asking about how to store website data

Comment: For that you can use javascript interfacing to get the callbacks etc

Comment: i saw this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/392603/Android-addJavaScriptInterface) for javascript but i don't want to put website page in to assets folder is there any other way for same question?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is it depends on your requirements. All have their benefits and trade offs around speed of different operations and simplicity.

I suggest you do some reading before making a choice. An article like this one will be a good start.

https://notes.devlabs.bg/realm-objectbox-or-room-which-one-is-for-you-3a552234fd6e

Personally I've been using Realm for over 2 years and it is fast for stuff like querying, however there are some technical caveats so make sure you read the documentation before you commit to it. I'm saying this because I didn't read it all, and although I don't regret using Realm, there is certainly some things that would have been useful to know before committing to it.

If Realm does interest you take a look at this documentation.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Comment: Actually, **i my question was how to store website data**,
i knew many data storage is available for  storing the data .